# How to loop over the nested formGroup controls

Tags: angular

I'm building an angular app which has nested formGroup controls. It should look something like the following.

[image]

Each row will have it's own input field and the user has option to add more rows too. I was able to add the column as a formGroup and it looks something like this.

[image]

The problem is I'm getting the following error when trying to loop over the controls object. The error message in the console:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
> type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.

In the front-end I'm getting this error message

> Error in src/app/app.component.html (26:28) Property 'controls' does
> not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

Here's the link to [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-ahlyj9.stackblitz.io/)

***app.component.ts***

```
  public form!: FormGroup;
  public result: any;

  public normalControls: any;
  public blockControls: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //console.log(JsonData);
    this.creatForm();
  }

  creatForm() {
    var JsonData = this.Json();
    this.normalControls = JsonData.controls.filter(
      (x: any) => x.type !== 'block'
    );
    this.blockControls = JsonData.controls.filter(
      (x: any) => x.type === 'block'
    );
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fName: [null],
      lName: [null],
      addresses: this.addressForm(),
      contacts: this.fb.array([this.contactFrom()]),
    });
  }

  addressForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      address1: [null],
      address2: [null],
      country: [null],
      state: [null],
    });
  }

  get addresses() {
    return this.form.get('addresses') as FormGroup;
  }

  get contacts() {
    return this.form.get('contacts') as FormArray;
  }

  contactFrom() {
    var obj: any = {};
    var blockControls = this.blockControls;
    blockControls.forEach((el: any) => {
      var block = el.block;
      block.forEach((item: any) => {
        obj[item.name] = [null];
      });
      var x = '';
    });
    return this.fb.group(obj);
  }

  onSave() {
    console.log(this.form.getRawValue());
    this.result = this.form.getRawValue();
  }

  addNewContacts() {
    this.contacts.push(this.contactFrom());
  }

  removeContact(i: Required<number>) {
    this.contacts.removeAt(i);
  }

  log(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  Json() {
    return {
      controls: [
        {
          name: 'RefNumber',
          label: 'Reference Number',
          value: '',
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: '',
          class: 'form-control',
          validators: {
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'ReceivingOfficer',
          label: 'Receiving Officer',
          value: '',
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: '',
          class: 'form-control',
          validators: {
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'DateReceived',
          label: 'Date Received',
          value: '',
          type: 'date',
          placeholder: '',
          class: 'form-control',
          validators: {
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
          },
        },
        {
          name: '',
          label: '',
          value: '',
          type: 'block',
          block: [
            {
              name: 'Name',
              label: 'Name',
              value: '',
              type: 'text',
              placeholder: '',
              class: 'form-control',
              validators: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 2,
              },
            },
            {
              name: 'Identification',
              label: 'Identification',
              value: '',
              type: 'text',
              placeholder: '',
              class: 'form-control',
              validators: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 2,
              },
            },
            {
              name: 'comments',
              label: 'Comments',
              value: '',
              type: 'text',
              placeholder: '',
              class: 'form-control',
              validators: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 2,
              },
            },
          ],
          placeholder: '',
          class: '',
          validators: {},
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

***app.component.html***

```
<h3>Contacts</h3>
<hr />
<div class="card" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="card-header">
    <label>User Contacts</label>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="addNewContacts()">
      Add New Contact
    </button>
    <hr />
    <ng-container
      formArrayName="contacts"
      *ngFor="let o of contacts.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <b>Contact {{ i + 1 }}</b>
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-danger mx-3 mt-3"
        (click)="removeContact(i)"
      >
        &times;
      </button>
      <hr />
      <ng-container
        formArrayName="o"
        *ngFor="let p of o.controls; let i = index"
      >
        {{ log(p) }}
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-center">
    <button (click)="onSave()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card mt-2">
  <div class="card-header">Result</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <code>
      <pre>
                {{ result | json }}
            </pre
      >
    </code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the stackblitz editor code. The link you have shared is just for the preview

Comment: Hello, @Red. Try to use `FormArray` instead of regular `FormGroup`. You can put your controls in the `FormArray` and loop over them with `this.myFormArray.getRawValue().forEach()` method in your `.ts` file or with `*ngFor` in a template. See Angular docs - https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: @MehyarSawas - I have updated the question with the code. Something is wrong with stackblitz, it's struggling to load.

Comment: you has a `<ng-container  formArrayName="o">` in your .html, but not in code

Comment: Thank you for your code. So, the problem is that in the `.html` you have - `<ng-container formArrayName="o" *ngFor="let p of o.controls; let i = index">` that actually is not `FormArray` but is a `FormGroup` that has `controls` property not as `Array` like `FormArray` but as `{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }` an object. Your function `contactFrom()` returns `FormGroup` of objects and you can not loop over an `object` then.